# FirebaseError: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implement the fcm Push notification in the react website using webspack.

**I have created the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in the public**

```
// [START initialize_firebase_in_sw]
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.3/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.3/firebase-messaging.js');
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({ 'messagingSenderId': '332364892095' });
// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler((payload) => {
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.'
    // icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };
  alert("called")
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
// [END background_handler]
```

I added the  `"gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"` in `manifest.json` file.

**I have created the `init-fcm.js` file in `src` folder.**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDuL6CgCdHYfsaAgw9Iom7CwLcCg29BS4E",
  authDomain: "filmthere-fa6e0.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://filmthere-fa6e0.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "filmthere-fa6e0",
  storageBucket: "filmthere-fa6e0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "332364892095",

};
export default firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

**Here is my `App.js` File**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Footer from './Footer'
import Main from './Main';
import firbaseApp from "./init-fcm";
import * as firebase from "firebase";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(firebase.messaging.isSupported()){
    // messaging.onMessage(this.handleBgCb);
    firbaseApp.messaging().requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
          firbaseApp.messaging().getToken()
            .then(currentToken => {
              if (currentToken) {

                console.log('token',currentToken)
                // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                // updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
              } else {
                // Show permission request.
                console.log(
                  "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
                );

                // Show permission UI.
                // updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
                // setTokenSentToServer(false);
              }
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);

              // showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
              // setTokenSentToServer(false);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
        });
    }

}

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Main />
          <Footer />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But it Gives this error while the page is load.

> FirebaseError: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default
>   service worker. ServiceWorker script at
>   http://localhost:8090/firebase-messaging-sw.js for scope
>   http://localhost:8090/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope encountered
>   an error during installation. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-regist

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are there any solution you achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding a solution for it as well but I found nothing on stackOverflow , but in a you tube video that guy created  file name " firebase-messaging-sw.js "  and it fixed the error . And it worked for me as well .

This is the error I was getting

FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).